# Python StringVar - get function returning nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a GUI app using the tkinter module in Python (mainly just to improve my Python skills, we're using it in GCSE Computer Science), however I've hit an annoying issue that I cannot figure out.

I have a UI that consists of multiple labels and entry boxes placed using the grid method (probably doesn't matter, but still). There are also 4 radio buttons. When a button on the UI is clicked (the Next button in this case), the values from the relevant entry boxes are stored in a dictionary, which is then appended to a list in the class.

My issue arises when I store the values into a dictionary - the value I'm getting from the `StringVar()` attached to the radiobuttons is always empty - a blank string, it would appear.

The class in question is below. I'm calling the `get()` method in the `next(self)` function.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

CreateQuizApp.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from TriviaTools import TriviaTools

class CreateQuizApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.deiconify()

        self.parent.geometry("600x300")
        self.parent.title("New Quiz")

        self.title=""
        self.questions=[]

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        if self.title is "": 
            titleLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Enter Quiz Title:")
            titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)

            titleEntry = Entry(self.parent)
            titleEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E)

            nextButton = Button(self.parent, text="Next", command=self.next)
            nextButton.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

            self.questionLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Enter Question:")

            self.questionEntry = Entry(self.parent)

            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

            self.answer1Label = Label(self.parent, text="Enter Answer 1:")
            self.answer2Label = Label(self.parent, text="Enter Answer 2:")
            self.answer3Label = Label(self.parent, text="Enter Answer 3:")
            self.answer4Label = Label(self.parent, text="Enter Answer 4:")

            self.answer1Entry = Entry(self.parent)
            self.answer2Entry = Entry(self.parent)
            self.answer3Entry = Entry(self.parent)
            self.answer4Entry = Entry(self.parent)

            self.categoryLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Category:")
            self.categoryEntry = Entry(self.parent)

            self.correctAnswer = StringVar()

            self.correctAnswerLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Correct Answer:")
            self.correctAnswer1 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="1", variable=self.correctAnswer, value="1", anchor=CENTER)
            self.correctAnswer2 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="2", variable=self.correctAnswer, value="2", anchor=CENTER)
            self.correctAnswer3 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="3", variable=self.correctAnswer, value="3", anchor=CENTER)
            self.correctAnswer4 = Radiobutton(self.parent, text="4", variable=self.correctAnswer, value="4", anchor=CENTER)

            self.correctAnswer1.select()
            self.correctAnswer2.deselect()
            self.correctAnswer3.deselect()
            self.correctAnswer4.deselect()

            self.pointsLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Points:")
            self.penaltyLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Penalty:")

            self.pointsEntry = Entry(self.parent)
            self.penaltyEntry = Entry(self.parent)

            self.explanationLabel = Label(self.parent, text="Explanation:")

            self.explanationEntry = Entry(self.parent)

            #self.correctAnswer.set(1)

            self.titleLabel = titleLabel
            self.titleEntry = titleEntry
            self.nextButton = nextButton
        else:
            try:
                self.titleEntry.destroy()
                self.titleLabel.destroy()
            except:
                pass

            self.nextButton.grid_forget()

            self.categoryLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.categoryEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.questionLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.questionEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.answer1Label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.answer2Label.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.answer3Label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.answer4Label.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W+E)

            self.answer1Entry.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)
            self.answer2Entry.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)
            self.answer3Entry.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)
            self.answer4Entry.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.correctAnswerLabel.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.correctAnswer1.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky=W+E)
            self.correctAnswer2.grid(row=9, column=2, sticky=W+E)
            self.correctAnswer3.grid(row=9, column=3, sticky=W+E)
            self.correctAnswer4.grid(row=9, column=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.pointsLabel.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.pointsEntry.grid(row=11, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.penaltyLabel.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.penaltyEntry.grid(row=12, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.explanationLabel.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky=W+E)
            self.explanationEntry.grid(row=14, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=W+E)

            self.nextButton.grid(row=17, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)

            self.finishedButton = Button(self.parent, text="Finished", command=self.finish)
            self.finishedButton.grid(row=17, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=E+W)

            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(8, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(9, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(11, weight=1)

            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
            self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

    def next(self):
        if self.title is "":
            widget = self.titleEntry
            title = widget.get()

            if title is "":
                return

            self.title = title
            self.parent.title(self.title)
            self.initUI()
        else:
            question = self.questionEntry.get()
            category = self.categoryEntry.get()
            points = self.pointsEntry.get()
            penalty = self.penaltyEntry.get()
            explanation = self.explanationEntry.get()

            answers = [self.answer1Entry.get(), self.answer2Entry.get(), self.answer3Entry.get(), self.answer4Entry.get()]

            if question is "" or category is "" or points is "" or penalty is "" or explanation is "":
                messagebox.showerror("Please fill in all fields!", "All fields must be filled in.")
                return

            for value in answers:
                if value is "":
                    messagebox.showerror("Please fill in all fields!", "All fields must be filled in.")
                    return

            question = {"category":category, "question":question, "answers":answers, "correct":self.correctAnswer.get(), "points":points, "penalty":penalty, "explanation":explanation}
            self.questions.append(question)

            self.categoryEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.questionEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.answer1Entry.delete(0, END)
            self.answer2Entry.delete(0, END)
            self.answer3Entry.delete(0, END)
            self.answer4Entry.delete(0, END)
            self.pointsEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.penaltyEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.explanationEntry.delete(0, END)

    def finish(self):
        tools = TriviaTools()

        file = tools.open_file(self.title+".trv", "w")

        lines = []

        lines.append(self.title+"\n")

        for question in self.questions:
            lines.append(question["category"]+"\n")
            lines.append(question["question"]+"\n")

            for answer in question["answers"]:
                lines.append(answer+"\n")

            lines.append(question["correct"]+"\n")
            lines.append(str(question["points"])+"\n")
            lines.append(str(question["penalty"])+"\n")
            lines.append(question["explanation"]+"\n")

        file.writelines(lines)
        file.close()

        self.parent.destroy()
```

Comment: You should really lookup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil your point being?

Comment: I was suggesting to cleanup the code a bit, at places where you repeat almost the same thing. After all, it can be programmatically done.

Comment: @LiamW I only see one place where you use `self.correctAnswer.get()` when setting the `question` variable, and it returns the correct output for me, verify by adding `print question`, I selected '2' and got `..., 'correct': '2'}`

Comment: @Fiver Strange. It doesn't output correctly for me - I just added a set one, and it always gives me what I passed into set.

Comment: please, post a minimal code that can be executed and that reproduces your problem. This will help us (and you) to evaluate where the problem is. Also I second Ashish Nitin Patil. For example, `for` loops are usually used to perform repetitive tasks coded in a few lines.

Comment: @LiamW I had to modify a couple things as I don't have your other class, but see if you can reduce the code and reproduce the issue with a minimal example.

Comment: All the code is needed - things are done in different places! All the variables are initialised in the `initUI()` method! If I use an for statement, I'll just have a ginormous list somewhere! Oh, actually, come to think of it... Hmmm.